# Check if all child components are rendered

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Is there any way I know whether all child components in blazor page are rendered or not?
I need to call JSInterop when all HTML are ready.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62057899/best-way-to-get-list-of-child-components-in-blazor

Comment: No, by that way, I can get all child components of a component, but what I want is some thing like `$( document ).ready()` in Jquery, which I allow me check whether child component rendered or not (HTML DOM was ready)

Comment: OnAfterRendered

Answer (score 0):

You can capture a reference to each child component using the ref attribute and add each one into some collection.

It may be helpful for you -> [Blazor get nested components by Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54859217/blazor-get-nested-components-by-reflection/54864611)

Thanks